# How to get result of HttpRequest?

Tags: asynchronous, dart

I'm writing the game for mobile using dart. My level-config stored as json. Via `httpRequest` I get JSON from server and then parse my json. It should create a Level-Object. I want to use it in my model. But I can't assign it to the level-reference in my model `(model.level)`. After `HttpRequest` it's value is still the same (`null`). My idea was also to use some art of callback, but I don't know how...

```
  static void load(final int levelNr, Game model) {
    final String path = "../json/$levelNr.json";

    HttpRequest.getString(path).then((lvlJson) {
      Map data = JSON.decode(lvlJson);
      Level level = _levelFromMap(data);
      model.level = level;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use `callback` or `async await`**

**1. Callback**

```
static void load(final int levelNr, void callbackFunction(Level level)) {
 final String path = "../json/$levelNr.json";

 HttpRequest.getString(path).then((lvlJson) {
  Map data = JSON.decode(lvlJson);
  Level level = _levelFromMap(data);
  callbackFunction(level);
 });
}
```

Usage:

```
load(levelNrValue, (level) {
  model.level = level;
  //refresh view or data to reflect the change in model.
})
```

**2. async and await**

```
static Future<Level> load(final int levelNr) async {
 final String path = "../json/$levelNr.json";

 final response = await HttpRequest.getString(path);
 Map data = JSON.decode(lvlJson);
 return _levelFromMap(data);
}
```

**Usage:**

1) Using callback at calling place:

```
load(levelNrValue).then((level) { 
  model.level = level;
  //refresh view or data to reflect the change in model.
});
```

2) Using async in calling place also:

```
final level = await load(levelNrValue);
model.level = level;
```

Note: the above two lines should be inside some async method.

```
void loadDate(int levelNrValue, Game model) async {
  final level = await load(levelNrValue);
  model.level = level;
  //refresh view or data to reflect the change in model.
}
```

Comment: It works, when I call for example `print(model.level.runtimeType)` inside of callback, for example:
`load(levelNrValue, (level) {
  model.level = level;
  print(model.level); // shows 'Instance of Level'
})`
But if I call it out of Callback function
`load(levelNrValue, (level) {
  model.level = level;
  print(model.level); // shows 'Instance of Level'
})
print(model.lelvel); // shows null
`
then the model.level still null

Comment: The print outside will execute before the assignment of `model.level`.

Comment: Now I understand... But... Can I execute "print" only after assignment? View and model using the data from Level.dart. So I need to work with only loaded data. That means, that I should place all my Code(for View and Modell) inside of callback...

Comment: Correct.. We have to keep the code inside callback... Once you have working solution with callback, try to implement the same the `async and await`. It's worth giving a try. After sometime, everyone will tend towards async and await :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the request is finishing in an error which might not be noticed.
Try adding a `catchError`:

```
static void load(final int levelNr, Game model) {
    final String path = "../json/$levelNr.json";

    HttpRequest.getString(path).then((lvlJson) {
      Map data = JSON.decode(lvlJson);
      Level level = _levelFromMap(data);
      model.level = level;
    })
    .catchError((Error error) {
      print(error.toString());
    });;
 }
```

Comment: `NullError: method not found: 'set$level' on null`